# Vim. How to force open file in new tab?

Tags: vim

1. Start vim
2. Open some `first.txt`
3. `:tabe second.txt`

Ok. We have two tab pages with first.txt and [active] second.txt

4. `:tabe first.txt`
5. Vim opened existing [first] tab page.

How to make vim always open NEW tab page?

Comment: Set this in you `.vimrc`: `:au BufAdd,BufNewFile * nested tab sball`

Comment: @syntagma that will always open all buffers in separate tabs. That's completely different from what was asked.

Comment: @svak the behavior you describe is not how vim behaves by default. Do you still observe this when starting with `vim -u NONE`?

Comment: Be careful if you add this as a default behaviour, because some plugin might use `BufAdd` or `BufNewFile` to show some sort of "popup" window and that would mess their layout.